# Stop jQuery from running when mouse is hovering over box on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

I have this jQuery:

```
jQuery('.slidey').on('hover',function(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1151) {
    jQuery(this).children('.post-content').stop().slideToggle(180);
}});
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where if I load the page, and my mouse is already in the position of the sliding box, then the box will slide up and the toggle will be reversed... So - the toggle state I want to show when I hover shows when I don't hover, and it is hidden when I do, rather than the other way round..!

How can I get the jQuery to ignore the mouse if it is already positioned over it on page load to stop this toggle from being reversed? I've had a look around at other questions on here and the solutions don't seem to work.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the specification for `.hover` [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), I would recommend using BOTH the hoverIn and hoverOut and then instead of using `slideToggle`, use `slideDown` and `slideUp` such as:

```
jQuery('.slidey').hover( 
  function(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1151) {
      jQuery(this).children('.post-content').stop().slideDown(180);
    }
  },
  function(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1151) {
      jQuery(this).children('.post-content').stop().slideUp(180);
    }
  }
);
```

Also, found here [See Additional Notes](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much, this solution works perfectly. I'm having a little trouble understanding how though, could you clear this up for me? I took a look at the spec and I see that the `.hover` function consists of first `mouseIn` and then `mouseOut`. so if I understand correctly, the code you have written for me means that when the mouse enters, it slides down, and when it leaves, it should slide up, of course, this is not the case... Could you clear up where I'm going wrong with this? Again, thanks for the solution, really appreciate the help.

Comment: @SamBrown - check your window width. I had to reduce the check value to get it to work. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h5rc95x/1/) help illustrate what is happening.